# Getting previous version of row text in bindingsource before AcceptChanges

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

I have a small Winforms program that I'm testing with.  What I'm trying to do is get the row text  *before* changes were made in the datagridview row.  Right now, in the actual program (not this test version), when the user presses 'Save' I am updating records in a database.  However, the users would like a log of the values *before* they were changed.  That's what I'm trying to figure out... how to get the values before they were changed.

The UI looks like this:

[image]

The code looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataGridViewDemo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public DataTable DataTable { get; set; }

        public Form1()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            // Initialize table and populate with data.
            this.DataTable = new DataTable();
            this.DataTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            this.DataTable.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));
            this.DataTable.Rows.Add("Tom", 45);
            this.DataTable.Rows.Add("Erin", 36);
            this.DataTable.Rows.Add("Tom, Jr.", 9);
            this.DataTable.AcceptChanges();

            // Bind the datasource to the data table.
            this.bindingSource1.DataSource = this.DataTable;
            this.dgv.DataSource = this.bindingSource1;
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get all changes made to the rows.
            var changes = ((DataTable)this.bindingSource1.DataSource).GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);
            if (changes == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Now I've got every row change to the data table...
            var changedRows = changes.Rows;

            //.. but how can I get the same rows /before/ they were changed?
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried using the CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event, but it fires on every keystroke in a cell.  I'm wondering if the binding source contains a *before* image of the datatable before I AcceptChanges on it (which I'm not doing yet, in the program above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When changes are made to data rows, the dataset retains both the original (Original) and new (Current) versions of the row. For example, before calling the AcceptChanges method, your application can access the different versions of a record (as defined in the DataRowVersion enumeration) and process the changes accordingly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kd9zhee.aspx

Comment: Oh, man, that looks like something I can work with.  Thank you!